# Spring Integration SFTP: removing or noving multiple files

Tags: java, spring, integration, spring-integration, sftp

With Spring Integration I want to move or remove multiple files or non-empty folders at once on a remote SFTP server. But I can't seem to find support for this in the official [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html), as it seems that this is unsupported. Although the documentation isn't always correct anyway.

I was thinking by using the `int-sftp:outbound-gateway` with the `rm` command with a payload the directory name. But it doesn't seem to work. I haven't tried it with `mv` yet, but I'm wondering if anyone has any experience with this behaviour in Spring Integration.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from your question : are the files you want to remove local to your application or remote, on the SFTP server ?

Below is an example of what I have in one my app, maybe that can help : incoming messages (with file name in payload) are first sent to remote SFTP server, and then are deleted locally

```
<integration:publish-subscribe-channel
    id="sftpChannel" />

<!-- The processed file will be sftped to the server -->
<sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter"
    session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" channel="sftpChannel" order="1"
    charset="UTF-8" remote-file-separator="/" remote-directory="${sftp.remote.directory}"
    remote-filename-generator-expression="payload.getName()" mode="REPLACE" />

<!-- sftped file will be removed from the staging folder -->
<integration:service-activator
    input-channel="sftpChannel" output-channel="nullChannel" ref="sftpFileDeleter"
    method="deleteAfterSftpingFile" order="2" />
```

with SftpFileDeleter being

public class SftpFileDeleter {

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger
        .getLogger(SftpFileDeleter.class);

@ServiceActivator
public void deleteAfterSftpingFile(Message<File> fileMessage) throws IOException{
    Path fileToDeletePath = Paths.get(fileMessage.getPayload().getAbsolutePath());
    Files.delete(fileToDeletePath);

    LOGGER.info("[SENT]File Sent to Sftp Server and deleted:"+fileToDeletePath.getFileName());


}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to delete or move multiple files remotely on the SFTP server. Your answer gives me an idea though, deleting with Java instead of using XML. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at this example ?

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/sftp/src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/SftpOutboundGatewaySample-context.xml

It looks like that's exactly what you want to do. One thing you may do wrong though, is that according to the docs (http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html , section 26.7),  payload of your incoming message doesn't have to contain the filename : **you need to be careful with the headers though**, and set correct properties (file_remoteDirectory / file_remoteFile in your case) with proper values.

I don't know your current config, but you would probably need a message transformer just before the SFTP Outbound Gateway, to move the information from the payload to the header of the message.

Comment: That's the way I currently do it. But it's way too slow for 10k-25k files. Just because it will create a new connection to the SFTP server for every file to delete. Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: Assuming most of the files are in similar directories and you want to clean all directories (and not file by file), you could have splitter / aggregator that internally goes through your 25k messages and saves in a List all the directories. Once aggregator gets triggered after all messages have been processed, the aggregator can release one message per directory to clean, in which file_remoteFile is "*" .

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with writing my own code on top of Spring, as @Vincent_F suggested. First of all you have to `autowire` an SFTP session factory like so:

```
@Autowired
private DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory;
```

After which the session can be used to, in my case, rename the directory. This should probably also work with the default Spring DSL or XML, but I couldn't get it to work... Here is my own code relevant to this use case:

```
SftpSession session = sftpSessionFactory.getSession();

try {
    if (!session.exists(sftpConfiguration.getOtherRemoteDirectory())) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Remote directory does not exists... Continuing");
    }

    for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry : session.list(sftpConfiguration.getRemoteDirectory())) {
        if (entry.getFilename().equalsIgnoreCase(sftpConfiguration.getOtherDirectory())) {
            session.rename(sftpConfiguration.getOtherRemoteDirectory(), String.format("%s%s-%s",
                    sftpConfiguration.getRemoteDirectory(), sftpConfiguration.getReportDirectory(),
                    this.createDate(new Integer(entry.getAttrs().getMTime()).longValue() * 1000)));
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("Could not rename remote directory.", e);
}
```